# Creating a NSManagedObject and passing it between view controllers

Tags: iphone, core-data

So I'm not sure how this is supposed to work.  I have a NSManagedObject subclass called Map.  It gets created like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
   // create map with below initializer
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapView.visibleMapRect);

   self.map = [Map mapWithName:nil: region:region inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext;
}

+ (Map *)mapWithName:(NSString *)mapName region:(MKCoordinateRegion)region inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    Map *aMap = [Map mapWithName:mapName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    aMap.centerLatitude = @(region.center.latitude);
    aMap.centerLongitude = @(region.center.longitude);
    aMap.latitudeDelta = @(region.span.latitudeDelta);
    aMap.longitudeDelta = @(region.span.longitudeDelta);

    return aMap;
}
```

I put the Map object in here since the delegate method

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView
```

does not always get called, but the regionDidChangeAnimated: does.  The problem is, this can create anywhere from 1-7 map objects in the NSManagedObjectContext.  So that when I go to the next screen, even though I only have one self.map property, my fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects will have 1-7 map objects in it and populate the TableViewController on the next page with a bunch of the same object.  Is there a better way to do this?  I thought I could just make a regular MapTemp : NSObject that mimics the NSManagedObject and only create the Map : NSManagedObject when I need to save the Map or something.

Thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want more than one object, then *why do you create them*?
Either *delete* the ones you don't want, or, better, *update* the existing one.